# Is there a Path.Combine for registry key paths in .net?

Tags: .net, path, registry

I want to combine registry key path fragments together without worrying about correct backslash separators, which is similar in spirit to Path.Combine... or can I perhaps just abuse Path.Combine for this purpose?

Comment: PS now it's answered I have another question - will it also work on mono?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Path.Combine` for this.

Comment: You can't use Path.Combine if your fragments contains characters that are invalid for filenames, but valid registry key values.

Comment: You also cannot use Path.Combine if your registry value contains a drive specifier e.g. Path.Combine("HKCU\Key\", "C:\some.dll"); would return just C:\some.dll. This is noted in the MSDN article: "If path2 includes a root, path2 is returned". Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx